# Get onActivityResult show on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I write Android code to read QR code. 
If I don't use fragment, It's work very well.
But when I use fragment,result not show.

I don't use

```
startActivityForResult(.....)
```

So my question is different this  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

I don't have more experience about fragment.

```
btnReadParkingCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if(result!=null)
    {
        if(result.getContents()==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            txtHiden.setText(result.getContents());
            Toast.makeText(activity,result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing @override and try again

Comment: It's not show result :(

Comment: try to move onActivityResult in parent activity of Fragment and get response using interface. Just give it a try. Or i can suggest you another library for QRCode

Comment: Let's me try :D

Comment: @Babul Patel it works for me. Thank you very much. But, can you suggest me another library for QRcode. Use my lib seem uncomfortable.

Comment: if are using Surfaceview for camera then https://github.com/nisrulz/qreader this library gives the best result for your requirement.

Comment: I never use before. Let's me try this. Thank you.